# Link Domain with Nginx and Tomcat with a specific Port and Folder

Tags: windows, jsp, nginx, tomcat, cloud

I have a JSP application running on a Tomcat server with Port 8070
the root directory of the application is called myapp and it's accessed via *localhost:8070/myapp/*

Now I am trying to host it under a domain myapp.com on a Windows VM with Nginx and tomcat

Could someone help me how to do the Nginx configuration for the above scenario?

Comment: This is not a programming question and you would get a better answer on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). BTW: there are already plenty of similar questions there, e.g. [this one](https://serverfault.com/q/293348/530633).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.